# How to add a firewalld rich rule that will allow only 2 FTP connections per minute to the FTP server?

Tags: linux, security, ftp, vsftpd, firewalld

I have used following firewalld rich rule. But it is allowing me more than two FTP connections in a minute. I expected that it could allow only two connections.

> firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule service name=ftp limit value=2/m
>   accept'

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with above rule or do we have any other way we can do using firewalld rich rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easier adding the rule in `/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml`.
This should work, but I'm not sure if `m` (minute) is supported, `h` (hour) seems to be:

```
<rule family="ipv4">
    <service name="ftp"/>
    <log prefix="ftp fw limit 2/m " level="warning">
      <limit value="2/m"/>
    </log>
    <accept>
      <limit value="2/m"/>
    </accept>
  </rule>
```

Also, make sure, that there is no other accept rule for ftp!

[Source](http://www.win.tue.nl/~vincenth/ssh_rate_limit_firewalld.htm)